# powershell add action to combobox

Tags: powershell

at the moment, i want to build a powershell gui. the form is running fine, so there are no problems. now i want to add an event for my selection, for example starting another script choosing "item1" and another script choosing "item2" and so on. how can i achieve that? thanfs for any help.
This is what i have actually.

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Combobox"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True

$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
 {
     foreach ($objItem in $objCombobox.SelectedItem)
         {$x += $objItem}
     $objForm.Close()
 }
})

$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
 {$objForm.Close()}})

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"

$OKButton.Add_Click(
{
     foreach ($objItem in $objCombobox.SelectedItem)
         {$x += $objItem}
     $objForm.Close()
})

$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "please choose"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objCombobox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Combobox 
$objCombobox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$objCombobox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 

[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Item 1")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Item 2")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Item 3")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Item 4")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Item 5")

$objCombobox.Height = 70
$objForm.Controls.Add($objCombobox) 
$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

$x
```

Comment: Why are you defining `$objForm.Add_KeyDown` twice? `$x` has no meaning in the script block on these events unless it is defined as having the script or global scope (use like `$script:x`). Add a `SelectionChanged` event to the combobox and in there you can react on whatever selection is made.

Comment: i dont't know the SelectionChanged code. how do it looks like in my code? could cou give me an advise?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `SelectedIndexChanged`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continuing on my comment, below the revised script

```
$x =  # the return variable which is updated in the OK Click event
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$objForm               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$objForm.Text          = "Combobox"
$objForm.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$objForm.KeyPreview    = $True
$OKButton              = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,120)
$OKButton.Size         = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text         = "OK"
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$OKButton.Add_Click({
     $script:x = $objCombobox.SelectedItem  # there is only one SelectedItem
     $objForm.Close()
})

$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

# using this, you do not need the Add_KeyDown events to react on clicking the OK or Cancel button
$objForm.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$objForm.CancelButton = $CancelButton

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "please choose"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 


$objCombobox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Combobox 
$objCombobox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$objCombobox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objCombobox.Height = 70

[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Item 1")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Item 2")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Item 3")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Item 4")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Item 5")
$objCombobox.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({
    # for demo, just write to console
    Write-Host "You have selected '$($this.SelectedItem)'" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    # inside here, you can refer to the $objCombobox as $this
    switch ($this.SelectedItem) {
        "Item 1" { <# do something when Item 1 is selected #> }
        "Item 2" { <# do something when Item 2 is selected #> }
        "Item 3" { <# do something when Item 3 is selected #> }
        "Item 4" { <# do something when Item 4 is selected #> }
        "Item 5" { <# do something when Item 5 is selected #> }
    }
})

$objForm.Controls.Add($objCombobox) 
$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

# IMPORTANT clean up the form when done
$objForm.Dispose()

$x
```

<sup>As you can see, I have removed both `$objForm.Add_KeyDown()` event handlers, as they are not needed when you set `$objForm.AcceptButton = $OKButton` and `$objForm.CancelButton = $CancelButton`. Also, always remove the form from memory when done with it using `$objForm.Dispose()`</sup>

---

As per your comment, I understand you want to perform the selected action only after closing the form.

In that case also remove the `$OKButton.Add_Click()` event handler and just store the selected option in `$script:x` in the SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
$x =  # the return variable which is updated in the SelectedIndexChanged event handler
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$objForm               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$objForm.Text          = "Combobox"
$objForm.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$objForm.KeyPreview    = $True
$objForm.Topmost       = $True

$OKButton              = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,120)
$OKButton.Size         = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text         = "OK"
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton              = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size         = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text         = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel

$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

# using this, you do not need the Add_KeyDown events to react on clicking the OK or Cancel button
$objForm.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$objForm.CancelButton = $CancelButton

$objLabel          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20)
$objLabel.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$objLabel.Text     = "please choose"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objCombobox          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Combobox
$objCombobox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40)
$objCombobox.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$objCombobox.Height   = 70

[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Item 1")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Item 2")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Item 3")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Item 4")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Item 5")
$objCombobox.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({
    # inside here, you can refer to the $objCombobox as $this
    # set the return variable to the SelectedItem
    $script:x = $this.SelectedItem  # there is only one SelectedItem

    # or, if you want it to, you can start the action here immediately without leaving the form:
    # switch ($this.SelectedItem) {
        # "Item 1" { <# do something when Item 1 is selected #> }
        # "Item 2" { <# do something when Item 2 is selected #> }
        # "Item 3" { <# do something when Item 3 is selected #> }
        # "Item 4" { <# do something when Item 4 is selected #> }
        # "Item 5" { <# do something when Item 5 is selected #> }
    # }
})
$objForm.Controls.Add($objCombobox) 

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
$dialogResult = $objForm.ShowDialog()

# IMPORTANT clean up the form when done
$objForm.Dispose()

if ($dialogResult -eq 'OK' -and ![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($x)) {
    # the form was not cancelled and a selection was made

    # for demo, just write to console
    Write-Host "You have selected '$($x)'" -ForegroundColor Cyan

    switch ($x) {
        "Item 1" { <# do something when Item 1 is selected #> }
        "Item 2" { <# do something when Item 2 is selected #> }
        "Item 3" { <# do something when Item 3 is selected #> }
        "Item 4" { <# do something when Item 4 is selected #> }
        "Item 5" { <# do something when Item 5 is selected #> }
    }
}
else {
    Write-Host "You have cancelled the dialog or did not select anything"
}
```

---

Ok, apparently now you want the form to stay after making a choice and clicking the `OK` button (and thus perform the chosen action).

In that case, you can simplify like this:

```
$x = @() # the return variable (an array with all selections made in order)
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$objForm               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$objForm.Text          = "Combobox"
$objForm.Size          = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$objForm.KeyPreview    = $True
$objForm.Topmost       = $True

$OKButton              = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,120)
$OKButton.Size         = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text         = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({ 
    $selected = $objCombobox.SelectedItem
    $script:x += $objCombobox.SelectedItem
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($selected)) {
        Write-Host "Performing action $($selected)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $objLabel.Text = "Performing action $($selected)"
        switch ($selected) {
            "Item 1" { <# do something when Item 1 is selected #> }
            "Item 2" { <# do something when Item 2 is selected #> }
            "Item 3" { <# do something when Item 3 is selected #> }
            "Item 4" { <# do something when Item 4 is selected #> }
            "Item 5" { <# do something when Item 5 is selected #> }
        }
        $objLabel.Text = "Please choose"
        $objCombobox.SelectedIndex = -1   # reset the combobox to blank
    }
})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton              = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size         = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text         = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

# using this, you do not need the Add_KeyDown events to react on clicking the OK or Cancel button
$objForm.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$objForm.CancelButton = $CancelButton

$objLabel          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20)
$objLabel.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$objLabel.Text     = "please choose"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objCombobox          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Combobox
$objCombobox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40)
$objCombobox.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
$objCombobox.Height   = 70

[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Item 1")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Item 2")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Item 3")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Item 4")
[void] $objCombobox.Items.Add("Item 5")

$objForm.Controls.Add($objCombobox) 

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
$dialogResult = $objForm.ShowDialog()

# IMPORTANT clean up the form when done
$objForm.Dispose()

if ($dialogResult -ne 'Cancel' -or $x.Count -eq 0) {
    # the form was cancelled or no selection was made
    # for demo, just write to console
    Write-Host "You have cancelled the dialog or did not select anything.."
}
else {
    Write-Host "The selection(s) you made were $($x -join ', ')" -ForegroundColor Cyan
}
```

Comment: Thats pretty nice, thanks for that. But the script i choose starts immediately whitout hitting the ok button

Comment: works perfect, but would be nice if the form keeps open after choosing a script

Comment: @chkdsk Ok, I added a final code piece to this question. Please see the edit

Comment: that also works perfectly. really...thank you very very much. I have still one question. please excuse my many questions. is it possible that the selection is always reset

Comment: thank you very much. you're my hero of the week. works pretty nice

Comment: sorry for reporting back. i just have checked and the script always remeber the last used script and start it too, doesn't matter what i choose. for example i start script 1 and after that script 2 it always start script 1 and 2

Comment: @chkdsk Yes, my bad. It should have been`switch ($selected)`, not `switch ($script:x)`.. Updated now

Comment: have also found out in the meantime. nevertheless thank you very much