# Combobox Issues

Tags: powershell, combobox

Hei, im very new to coding so excuse the lake of knowledge.

im haveing issuse with a Powershell program that i have writen, and i had it working for a bit but some how i commited the cardinal sin of not backing up my code. in short i have created a combobox that lists NetAdapters and adds them to the combobox then its splits it in to variables for IP, Default IP Mac adress and if the adapter is UP.
using a foreach.

i have some basic understanding of why its not working but i'm having issues getting to the solution.

so what i want is what ever is selected in the combobox is what i want the variables to store. but it keep Storing the last Adapter, the last item in the list in this case the WI FI adapter.

What i need is for the selected Line to be saved outside of the loop not just inside.

Thanks for the help!

```
$Adapters = Get-NetAdapter

$sortedAdapters = $Adapters | Sort-Object { $\_.Status -ne 'Up' }, Name

foreach ($Adapter in $sortedAdapters) {
$Name = $Adapter.Name
$Mac = $Adapter.MacAddress
$Up = $Adapter.Status
$IPConfig = Get-NetIPConfiguration -InterfaceAlias $Name

if ($IPConfig) {
    $IP = $IPConfig.IPv4Address.IPAddress
    $DIP = $IPConfig.IPv4DefaultGateway.NextHop
    $AdapterInfo = "Adapter: $Name | IP: $IP | Status: $Up"
    $comboBox.Items.Add($AdapterInfo) | Out-Null
}

}

$upAdapterIndex = ($sortedAdapters.IndexOf($sortedAdapters) | Where-Object { $\_.Status -eq 'Up'      })

$comboBox.SelectedIndex = $upAdapterIndex
```

trail and error lots and lots of error since im very new to this im using Gpt as a guide to get things rolling. im not working as a programmer im just doing this as a hobby.

Comment: You need to add an action to the combobox so that when something is selected you can save it to another variable or do what you want to it. Specifically, I think you are going to need to add `Add_SelectedIndexChanged` to your comobox. Check out [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66598678/20473839) . The line `$objCombobox.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({` is where they add the action.

Comment: Thanks i Managed to fix it, I ended up changing it in to a function instead and now its effecting the variables outside of the foreach loop.